# How can i create a column with images and text with html and CSS

Tags: html, css

Im new at this programing world and i want/need to learn about creating this columns with images
[Image of description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k39Qk.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please post relevant code that you've tried --not images of code-- and a clear problem statement.

Comment: [This website](https://www.google.com/) makes it super easy to find programming resources, I highly recommend it

Comment: You answered your own question: _with HTML and CSS_. StackOverflow is not a code writing service. Please give it your best effort, and when you run into problems, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and update your question.

Comment: here you have a row *(or few)*, then *(another spreading)*  3 colums.  rows is basic block behavior , float, column css or display *(inlin-block, inline-table, table, table-cell, flex or grid)* to help you drawing 3 columns. what have you tried that failed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
#header{
 width:100%;
 text-align:center;
 padding:10px;
 font-size:30px;
}
#Title{
 width:100%;
 text-align:center;
 padding:10px;
 font-size:15px;
}
#row{
 width:100%;
 text-align:center;
 padding:5px;
}

.col{
 width:25%;
 height:100px;
 text-align:center;
 padding:5px;
  margin:2px;
  border:1px solid gray;
   display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="header"><span>test header</span></div>
<div id="Title">test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test  test test  test test  test test test test test test </div>
<div id="row">
  <div class="col"> </div>
  <div class="col"> </div>
  <div class="col"> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: why inline-block and not table-cell , grid or flex ? ;)

Answer (score 0):

I can think of 6 classics ways to draw column in the document flow.

Each with different behavior or side effect that might be minded :
*(borders and bg are to show differences)* **[pen to play with](https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/WZzGqx)**

```css
/* reset and commun styling */
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align:center;
}
.row {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 2em auto;
  border: solid;
  counter-reset: div;
  position: relative;
}
.row:after {
  content: attr(class);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  border: solid;
  left: 0;
  background: yellow;
  font-size:1rem;
}
.row > div:before {
  counter-increment: div;
  content: counter(div);
}
.row :nth-child(2) {
  border: solid;
  border-width: 0 3px 0 3px;
  /* shows behavior of sibblings */
  padding: 1em 0;
}
.row div {
  background: gray;
}

/* float and side effect cured */
.row.float {
  display:table;/*instead overflow to trigger BFC*/
  /* overflow:hidden ; removed to show classname */
}
.row.float div {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
}

/* inline-block and side effect cured */
.row.inline-block {
  font-size: 0;
}
.row.inline-block div {
  font-size: 1rem;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 33.33%;
}

/* table and setting*/
.row.table {
  display: table;
  border-spacing: 0;
}
.row.table div {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 33.33%;
}

/* multiple column CSS , reset styling*/
.row.column {
  column-count:3;
  column-rule: inset 3px ;
  column-fill:balance;
  background:gray;
}
.row.column div { 
  background:lightgray;
  border:none;
  border-bottom:solid white;/* see my behavior */
}

/* flex-ible */
.row.flex {
  display: flex;
}
.row.flex div {
  flex: 1;
}

/* grid and grid setting */
.row.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}
```

```html
<div class="row float">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
<div class="row inline-block">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
<div class="row table">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
<div class="row column">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
<div class="row flex">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
<div class="row grid">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

with float and inline-block you can also use the faux column technic : https://alistapart.com/article/fauxcolumns (note how old and solid it still is )